# Como testar os locals em um render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testes, minitest

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, faço meus testes utilizando Ministest, porém estou com um problema ao testar o locals de um render... não sei como testar, exemplo:

Controller:

```
def salvou
   render('cadastro/salvou', locals: {id: params[:id]})
end
```

nesse caso o meu salvou é um arquivo js.

Teste:

```
it "Redireciona para o salvou" do
    [...]
    assert_template 'cadastro/salvou'
end
```

e o locals, como eu testo?

Grato!

Answer (score 1):

```
# assert that the "_customer" partial was rendered with a specific object
assert_template partial: '_customer', locals: { customer: @customer }
```

ref.: [ActionController::TestCase](http://blowmage.com/minitest-rails/ActionController/TestCase.html#method-i-assert_template)